# Singleton in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to implement "singleton" pattern in Kotlin. I wrote something like this.

```
class MySingleton {
    companion object {
        val instance = MySingleton
    }
}
```

But now users can create instances.

```
val mySingleton = MySingleton()
```

I want allow only this way.

```
val instance = MySingleton.instance
```

How can I ban using a constructor of my class?

Comment: You may also want to read about objects in Kotlin in the official documentation,.e.g. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html

Answer (score 3):

if you use an object instead of a class you may have better luck

ie.

```
object MySingleton {
    val thingA = 0
}
```